# How to invert colors in Altium for Soldermask application

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, altium, solder-mask, silkscreen

I am trying to invert black and white in Altium for the "Bottom Solder" *from this one [image]*to look this one
[image] from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ISmS7HuXSE. As it turns out, while doing screen printing the **white** part should be **black** while the **black** should be **White**. I appreciate your guidance on the way forward with Altium or any other PCB design software.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Film Wizard, under Tools. Select "invert".